# Proc sql calculate previous saturday or end of last week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sas, proc-sql

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
asof = CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       '1899-12-30T19:00:00') AS DATE)
```

Basically, I am trying to use previous week's Saturday as my filter on Proc Sql. No matter what day I run this query it should give me the date(not timestamp) of last Saturday

Thank you!

Comment: is it  SQL pass through code for teradata or SQL server.

Comment: yes, it is SQL pass through code for SQL server

Comment: Please show you're using it in a filter. In your example it's creating a variable and how you're filtering may affect the logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
%let last_saturday = intnx ('week.7', today()-1, 0);
%let last_saturday = %sysfunc(intnx (week.7, %sysfunc(today())-1, 0), yymmdd10.);
%put NOTE: &last_saturday;

%let last_saturday_sq = %sysfunc(quote(&last_saturday,%str(%')));
%put NOTE: &last_saturday_sq;

proc sql;
  … connection to … 
     (cast &last_saturday_sq as DATE) as asof
  …
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I am not sure why as it doesn't give me any error message.

Comment: try the same code without a macro variable, instead use a hard-coded value and see if the same 'did not work' happens.  If so, it's not the macro.  If things do work, it's somewhere in the macro/pass-through area.